# What does clean server option do

Tags: tomcat, server

Tomacat server gives an option- "*clean...*"
What doea this option do?
I have seen people cleaning the server before they start the application, but what exactly happens with the server?

Answer (score 0):

It deletes all published ressources and republishes from scratch